# Using FireDac to update only 1 of a duplicate row (no primary key or unique field)

Tags: delphi, ms-access, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have an old application I am supporting that uses a Microsoft Access database. The original table design did not add primary keys to every table. I am working on a migration program that among other things is adding and filling in a new primary key field (GUID) when needed.

This is happening in three steps:

1. Add a new guid field with no constraints
2. Fill the field with new unique guids
3. Add the primary key constraints

My problem is setting the unique guids when the table has duplicate rows.  Here is my code to set the guids.

```
  Query.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM ' + TableName);
  Query.Open;

  while Query.Eof = false do
  begin
    Query.Edit;
    Query.FieldByName(NewPrimaryKeyFieldName).AsGuid := TGuid.NewGuid;
    Query.Post;

    Query.Next;
  end;
```

FireDac generates an update statement that contains a where clause with all the original fields/values in the row (since there is no unique field for it to use). However, because the rows are complete duplicates the statement still updates two rows.

FireDac correctly errors with this message

```
Update command updated [2] instead of [1] record.
```

I can open up the database in Access and delete the duplicate records or assign them a unique guid by editing the table. I would like my conversion tool to automatically do this.

**Is there some way to work with these duplicate rows in FireDac? Either to update just one at a time, or to delete just one of them?**

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but am not sure, so not answering. Instead, start by adding an autonumber field to have a distinct identifier, and remove it after you've assigned the GUID

Comment: Why retain duplicates? If rows are truly duplicate (every field has same value as other record) use an aggregate or DISTINCT query to build dataset of unique values. MAKE TABLE from that dataset. Eliminate old table. Rename new table to old name.

Comment: Since you would like to keep the dups, I suggest you load the data from db to a dataset, then clear the table, add the primary field and use array DML to fill again the flushed data.

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout I don't need to keep the duplicates. I'm fine with them being deleted as well, but I could not figure out a way to get FireDac to delete just all but one of the duplicate records either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion there is no way to do it with just one SQL Statement.

I would do this:
 1. Copy the whole table without duplicates by using a new temp table

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM <TABLENAME>
```

2. Add the Keys
3. Delete old table content and copy new content from new table

**Notes:**

The DB Should be unavailable for everyone else for that Operation
2. Make **BACKUP** before

Comment: I can easily delete everything from the table with a sql statement. But how do I get FireDac to see the records in the original Query as inserts instead of updates?

Comment: SQL is Responsible for that. Firedac is only a "tool". Yout should use sometihing like that:
INSERT INTO dbo.EmployeeSales  
    SELECT BusinessEntityID, SalesYTD   
    FROM Sales.SalesPerson;